# Properties are making trouble

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I have added a Properties.cs file which contains properties that I am would use through out the application. I am getting NullReferenceException => `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is the code for Properties.cs

```
public class Properties
{
    private static string type1;

    public static string Type1
    {
        get
        {
            return type1;
        }
        set
        {
            type1= value;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I access this property in one of my form I am getting error. e.g.

```
if (Properties.Type1.Equals(string.Empty) || Properties.Type1.Equals(null))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Well, is `Type1` set, or does it still have the default `null` value?

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: Check that `Properties != null` and `Type1 != null` too!

Comment: @KingKing Instance fields also default to `null`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen **Reference** type fields defaults to null

Comment: @Belogix `Properties` is a class; it makes no sense to ask whether a class is `null` or not.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Yes, sorry! Didn't read the question fully, just skimmed to the bottom! My fault for being lazy!

Comment: `string` is a reference type. I'm only commenting to what is shown in the question. But KingKing (which has now removed his comment) said that static fields default to null and then seemed to hint that instance fields didn't. But yes, only reference type fields default to null.

Comment: ALWAYS check null first. C# will evaluate conditions one by one and ONLY check the next one if previous still true. so if the type1 is null it will crash as the if() check for value that don't exist. inverting your condition will fix your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you're making life hard for yourself. This is fine (or at least, just *as* fine, but a lot easier; whether or not static members is a good idea is a separate question, and depends a lot on the context):

```
public class Properties
{   
    public static string Type1 { get;set; }
}
```

Secondly, this has nothing to do with properties, and everything to do with calling a method on a `null` instance. You can just use `==` which avoids this issue, i.e.

```
if (Properties.Type1 == "" || Properties.Type1 == null)
{
    // Do something
}
```

However, for convenience there is also `string.IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Type1))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Should it be checking `null` first so `if (Properties.Type1 == null || Properties.Type1 == string.empty)` because it will throw an exception on the string check if it is `null`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you check for an empty string or null first in the code Marc has shown, it will work either way. You can't "dot" your way into the string however, but he's not doing that.

Comment: I am assigning value to the property e.g. Types.Type1 = "abc"; but the NullReferenceException appears. What is wrong with that.

Comment: @DhavalR would need to see a concrete example

Comment: Solved problem. One more thing. I have added a function to read xml file. A property that returns DataSet. From that DataSet property, I am assigning value (in get clause) for second property. e.g. `public static DataSet PropertiesList
        {
            get
            {
                ds1 = ReadXmlFile(LabelFileName);
                return ds1;
            }}` `public static string StringValue
        {
            get
            {
                stringValue = ControlProperties.Tables["ABC"].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                }}` Is it a proper way or anything wrong about it.?

Comment: @DhavalR and the question is?

Comment: EDIT : `public static string StringValue { get { stringValue = PropertiesList.Tables["ABC"].Rows[0][0].ToString(); }}`

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Type1))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: when I do Types.Type1 = something again NullReferenceException appears. How to set it.?

Comment: "Types"? What is that? You've only shown the implementation of the class `Properties`. And there is no way you can get a `NullReferenceException` in the code shown in your question if you're only assigning to the property.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the null and empty check in the wrong way.

The correct way is:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Type1))
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Type1))
{
    // Do something
}
```

but if you want a default value for this then I suggest you set it in a static constructor.